# i cant find the reason the program quits right after the first user input

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>;
#include <iostream>;
#define newline '\n';
using namespace std;




string initial;
string a;
string b;
string c;
string object;
string sword;
string testswing;

int main()
{

    cout << "you awake in a forest with no memory what do you do?";
    cout << newline;
    cin >> initial;
    if (initial == "look left" || initial == "look forward" || initial == "look behind"){
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a dense forest";
        cout << newline;

    }

    else (initial == "look right"); {
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a opening with a shape in the distance";
        cout << newline;
    }

    cin >> a;
    cout << newline;
    if (a == "go right")
    {
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a trap lucily you dident set it off. might want to SEARCH AREA before going into open areas";
        cout << newline;
        cin >> c;
        cout << newline;
        if (c == "go forward")
        {
            cout << newline;
            cout << "you arrive at the strange object do you want to INSPECT OBJECT?";
            cout << newline;
            if (object == "inspect object")
            {
                cout << newline;
                cout << "You see the object is a sword stuck in a stone";
                cout << newline;
                cin >> sword;
                if (sword == "pull sword");
                {
                    cout << newline;
                    cout << "the sword breaks free of the stone you have obtained the SHORT SWORD";
                        cout << newline;
                    cout << "use this item when appropriate by using the command SWING SWORD";
                    if (testswing == "swing sword");
                    {
                        cout << newline;
                        cout << "you swing the sword it hits the rock and breaks";
                        cout << newline;
                        cout << "we told you only to use the sword when appropriate now look what you've done your adventure is over already";
                            cout << newline;
                            system("pause");
                            return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << newline;
                cout << "the object draws you twards it seemingly by magic";
                cout << newline;
            }
        }
        else (c == "go left" || c == "go right"|| c == "go back");
        {
            cout << "there is nothing but empty feilds for miles you get lost and die";
            cout << newline;
            system("pause");
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "you cant go that way";
    }

}
```

the program quits just after the first user input no matter what the input is if its look left, look forward, look behind, or look right the program quits right after it and i cant find the issue. it says the program exited with a code 0 (0X0)

Comment: And when you used your debugger, to step through this code one line at a time, what observations did you make, regarding its execution flow?

Comment: `else (initial == "look right");` That's syntactically correct, semantically nonsense! `else if (initial == "look right")` might be what you are after. You also have a similar mistake later on.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The `cin>>initial` part of your code just takes in the user input till the first empty space

So when you enter LOOK LEFT  the initial string just contains LOOK which is why your code is not entering the IF statements.

Try getline(initial) instead of cin>>

check out this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

I found some issue with this program.

1. If you want multiple word input - use getline(cin, str) - cin will just take first word as input.
2. Once EOF (or any other error) is signalled, all attempts to input data fail. You must first clear the stream (cin.clear();) before attempting further input. So for every cin, use cin.clear() to flush the input buffer.

Now in you program if you are not using clear(), and enter multiple words input, than first word will be input to first string, second word of that input will be input for second "cin>>a", hence it doesn't stop there as it aleady got the input.

Try this :-

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>;
#include <iostream>;
#define newline '\n';
using namespace std;

string initial;
string a;
string b;
string c;
string object;
string sword;
string testswing;

int main()
{

    cout << "you awake in a forest with no memory what do you do?";
    cout << newline;
    getline(cin, initial);
    if (initial == "look left" || initial == "look forward" || initial == "look behind"){
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a dense forest";
        cout << newline;

    }

    else if(initial == "look right") {
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a opening with a shape in the distance";
        cout << newline;
    }
    cin.clear();
    getline(cin, a);
    cout << newline;
    if (a == "go right")
    {
        cout << newline;
        cout << "you see a trap lucily you dident set it off. might want to SEARCH AREA before going into open areas";
        cout << newline;
        cin >> c;
        cout << newline;
        if (c == "go forward")
        {
            cout << newline;
            cout << "you arrive at the strange object do you want to INSPECT OBJECT?";
            cout << newline;
            if (object == "inspect object")
            {
                cout << newline;
                cout << "You see the object is a sword stuck in a stone";
                cout << newline;
                cin >> sword;
                if (sword == "pull sword");
                {
                    cout << newline;
                    cout << "the sword breaks free of the stone you have obtained the SHORT SWORD";
                        cout << newline;
                    cout << "use this item when appropriate by using the command SWING SWORD";
                    if (testswing == "swing sword");
                    {
                        cout << newline;
                        cout << "you swing the sword it hits the rock and breaks";
                        cout << newline;
                        cout << "we told you only to use the sword when appropriate now look what you've done your adventure is over already";
                            cout << newline;
                            system("pause");
                            return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << newline;
                cout << "the object draws you twards it seemingly by magic";
                cout << newline;
            }
        }
        else (c == "go left" || c == "go right"|| c == "go back");
        {
            cout << "there is nothing but empty feilds for miles you get lost and die";
            cout << newline;
            system("pause");
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "you cant go that way";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```